# Embedding $\mbox{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and topologization

Tags: general-topology, matrices, group-theory, continuity

It is often said in loose language that the set of nxn matrices with real entries can be identified (?) with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, so a properly chosen topology on the latter space induces a topology on the set of matrices. Is this true? 
In other words and perhaps even more general, how can one structure the $\mbox{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ as a topological space?

Comment: You just described it: it has the same topology that $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ does. More generally, any finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ has a unique Hausdorff topology making addition and scalar multiplication continuous, namely the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is the dimension.

Comment: So if I define the Euclidean norm topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with its open sets as open balls, how are the open sets on $\mbox{Mat}_{n\times n} (\mathbb{R})$ defined?

Comment: The same way. The two are just isomorphic as vector spaces. There is nothing loose about this claim.

Comment: So this "embeddiing" I mentioned is just a vector space isomorphism, right?

Comment: Yes, and furthermore it's very easy to write down: you just list the coefficients of the matrix in whatever order you want.

Comment: Do you know of a book reference for this fact: "any finite-dimensional vector space over R has a unique Hausdorff topology making addition and scalar multiplication continuous, namely the topology of Rn where n is the dimension"? I wish to quote this result in something I write and its proof as a bibliographical item. Thanks!

Comment: Not off the top of my head. The proof is very short. Here's how it starts: pick a basis $e_1, \dots e_n$ of your vector space $V$. Consider the map $\mathbb{R}^n \to V$ given by sending $(x_1, \dots x_n)$ to $x_1 e_1 + \dots x_n e_n$, which is by hypothesis continuous. Now it's a nice exercise to show that it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: Another way of describing this topology is that it's the coarsest topology making every linear functional $V \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing an $n^2$-tuple as an $(n\times n)$-matrix, or vice versa, is just a restructuring of the index set. This may make a difference when it comes to algebraic operations with these things, but has no effect on the intended metric. However you look at it you have $$d^2(a,b)=\sum_\iota(a_\iota-b_\iota)^2\ ,$$
whereby $\iota\in[n^2]$ or $\iota\in [n]\times[n]$. It follows that the topologies are the same in both views. No deep theorems needed here.

Comment: Thank you. There is more thing. Your answer automatically establishes the major topological properties of $\mbox{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such as: compactness (non-compact), connectedness (non-connected), local-compactness (locally compact), right?

Comment: @DanielC: Indeed.